# ActionbarSherlock progress not visible after orientation change

Tags: android, screen-orientation, actionbarsherlock

Tested on 2.x physical and virtual devices.  Not tested on v3>

When the app starts, in either portrait or Landscape mode the progress bar shows in the actionbar fine.  After the FragmentActivity restarts following orientation change the progress no longer shows whether called from the onCreate code below (I've checked that the loaders are running and the code steps into setting progress bar to Boolean.TRUE) or from a simple button click event to `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);`

The onSaveInstanceState -> onCreate method is executed on orientation change, so the FragmentActivity is being stopped/started.

I've checked the references to make sure I'm using android.support.v4.view.
Also using ViewPagerIndicator with tabs/fragments - which shouldn't have any bearing.

The refresh button added to the actionbar by the fragments appears fine after orientation change/FragmentActivity restart.

---

Actually... I've just noticed something odd looking at the logcat debugs following an orientation change.  The FragmentActivity seems to start twice looking at the lines written to the logs, with onSaveInstanceState being called again followed by another onCreate ???

```
01-28 10:25:45.446: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onCreate

01-28 10:26:02.457: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): loaderHasStarted

01-28 10:26:02.457: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onCreateLoader 0

01-28 10:26:04.437: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onLoadFinished 0

01-28 10:26:04.447: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): loaderHasFinished

**Flip to landscape here**

01-28 10:29:07.567: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onSaveInstanceState

01-28 10:29:08.197: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onCreate

01-28 10:29:08.427: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): loaderHasStarted

01-28 10:29:08.427: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onCreateLoader 0

**Nothing happened here - I only changed orientation once**

01-28 10:29:08.458: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onSaveInstanceState

01-28 10:29:08.686: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onCreate

01-28 10:29:17.236: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): onLoadFinished 0

01-28 10:29:17.236: D/DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity(4728): loaderHasFinished
```

---

```
    public class DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
            implements OnLoaderListener,
            LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<LoaderStatus> {



        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // This has to be called before setContentView and you must use the
        // class in android.support.v4.view and NOT android.view
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");

        mAdapter = new ViewPagerTitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.tabindicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);


        // first check if we already have a running loader
        if ((savedInstanceState != null)
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey("RUNNING_LOADERS")) { 
            mRunningLoaders = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("RUNNING_LOADERS");
        }

        if (mRunningLoaders == null) {
            mRunningLoaders = new RunningLoadersList(); 
        }


        if (mRunningLoaders != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mRunningLoaders.size(); i++) {
                StartLoader(mRunningLoaders.get(i).id,
                        mRunningLoaders.get(i).args);
            }
        }

        if (getSupportLoaderManager().hasRunningLoaders()) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.TRUE);
        } else {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(Boolean.FALSE);
        }
    }


        @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("RUNNING_LOADERS", mRunningLoaders);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }



Nothing particularly interesting in the manifest.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.savant.donordetailsviewpagertitle"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

    <!-- Enable access to the the internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Enable access to the the network state -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:name="com.savant.donordetailsviewpagertitle.classes.DonorDetailsViewPagerTitle"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators">

        <activity android:name=".activities.DonorDetailsContainerFragmentActivity" 
                     android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Updated my Nexus S to 4.0.3.  I can confirm that this is still an issue for me on ICS where ActionbarSherlock is using the native actionbar (isn't it ?)